# Why are users created on the domain controller always part of the domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory

> Why are users created on the domain controller always part of the domain?

When I want to create a local user on the domain controller, `net user <username> <password> /add`, I find that the user is automatically included in the `Domain Users` group.

I want to create a local administrator account on the domain controller, not part of the domain, that is able to log onto the domain controller interactively and carry out administrative tasks.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local accounts are stored in a file called the [SAM database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Account_Manager). This exists on a domain controller - if you boot a domain controller [in restore mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Services_Restore_Mode) then the account you use to do this is just the local administrator account in the SAM database. However when Windows is running normally access to the SAM database is disabled and none of the accounts in it can be used. That means it is impossible to log on with a local account on a domain controller.

However this can be sort of done if you are happy to work from a command line and if you don't require network access. The trick is to log on as the local system account. Windows does not provide any way to do this but I have done it by writing a simple telnet server then running it as a service using the local system account. When you connect to the telnet server you are logged in as the system account not a domain account. The only restrictions are that it's command line only and the system account has no network access. If you're going to use a hack like this be very, very careful about security!

Though all this sounds like a horrible hack it does have legitimate uses. For example at work we use a management tool called N-able that allows remote access to a console on servers, and it does it using basically the technique I describe above. If I open a console on one of our domain controllers and use the *whoami* command I get:

[image]

**Footnote**

Windows has no built in method for opening a remote command prompt, but [as grawity mentions in a comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/937695/why-are-users-created-on-the-domain-controller-always-part-of-the-domain/937802#comment1217263_937802) The SysInternals psexec utility can do this, and the SysInternals utilities are provided and supported by Microsoft so this is at least semi official. Using psexec on one of my servers I get:

```
D:\temp\psexec>psexec64 \\cheddar -s cmd.exe

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>whoami
nt authority\system

C:\Windows\system32>exit
cmd.exe exited on cheddar with error code 0.
```

Comment: Did you reinvent SysInternals [psexec -s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)?

Comment: @grawity I first did this on Windows NT 3.1 before the Sysinternals utilities existed :-) However you make a good point. I'd forgotten that psexec could do that.

Comment: Point taken. Though hopefully the original "wide open" telnetd isn't in use now?

Answer (score 23):

No, this is not possible. Domain controllers don't have their own authentication database. It is replaced by Active Directory when promoted to a Domain Controller.

Comment: This answers "Is this possible?" from the question body, but does not answer "why" from the title. Any insigths on the "why" part?

Comment: `Domain controllers don't have their own authentication database. It is replaced by Active Directory when promoted to a Domain Controller` is the why. So this does answer the why.

Comment: "Why?" because that is the way that Microsoft designed this years ago. There was likely extensive through and research that went into this. The use case of a Domain Controller needing a local account was likely deemed minimal and eliminating it simplified the design requirements, programming etc.

Comment: @joeqwerty I am happy that it is just a comment, and not an answer. Because it is not a "why" and not an answer. The answer would be, why was it designed on this way.

Comment: @andleer I think it is already much better, however it still misses the references and the reasons. I think, there are many very different, non-trivial options, too. For example, the auth db of the DC could be also completely independent from its local SAM files (converting it essentially to some shared record storage), it might have major advantages in the security sense.

Comment: @peterh Only Microsoft may know why they designed it that way, but I doubt they know. During my handover, most "why" questions I had to answer with "I did because this was the first thing that came to mind, and it worked, and after that, never change a running system."

Comment: Honestly, if the question is "Why did Microsoft design it this way?" is the question, I'd VTC.  Any answer we would provide would be pure speculation (unless someone here worked on that project at MS circa 1999-ish?).

Comment: I was a MS MVP for Windows server back then and did some stuff with the "NT 5" beta team and went to a few meetings where design decisions were discussed. The argument then was that there wasn't really any such thing as a "local" administrator action on a domain controller as anything had the potential to affect the domain. Want to reboot the DC? Want to add or remove a role? Want to change the DNS settings on the network card? All potentially able to affect the ability of that DC to service it's domain and therefore not really "local admin" actions on a DC.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Not only the developers / OS designers themselves can be reasonable sources, and not only directly. There are many ways to do that. And, in my opinion, these would be very valuable informations. Things shouldn't be learned only by their *behavior*, they should be understood by their *workings*.

Comment: As @RobMoir states, the intent is that each DC is to be treated like any other. From a security point of view, you compromise one DC, you compromise the entire domain anyway. There is no point having per-DC permission sets. Also, Active Directory was always intended to be a *multi-master* directory service, unlike classic LDAP. The SYSTEM hive (and other registry parameters), permissions (e.g. for SYSVOL, ntds.dit) **must** be identical across all DCs. I agree that this (and the nature of BUILTIN groups etc) could be better documented in so many words.